# Getting SoftLayer Exception, token has expired

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I do the following steps usiong the Bluemix CLI.

I issue `bx login` with my apikey
I issue `bx sl init` using my SoftLayer username and API Key from SoftLayer

I issue `bx sl vlan list`, I get the following response.

> SoftLayer_Exception_EncryptedToken_InvalidToken: The token has
>   expired. (HTTP 500)

what Token has expired?

Answer (score 1):

Repeat the softlayer login procedure.

```
bx sl init
```

This will repeat the login and create a new token.

If that somehow fails, remove `~/.bluemix/plugins/softlayer/config.json` to force it to re-intialize.